# how to get a sibling of a clicked view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have 2 buttons

I want only one of them to be selected at most at a time.

how can i find a view's sibling while in `onClick` ?

I have tried:

siblingView =  v.getParent().findViewById(R.id.rightBtn);

but parentView has no `findViewById` method.

is it possible to get an ancestor view (even not direct) ? which is view for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getParentView` return type is an interface [ViewParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html) 
you can test if it is actually a View (or do not test, if you are sure), and downcast it to View.

Comment: is it possible to get an ancestor view (even not direct) ? which is view for sure?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you need some kind of tabs, not two buttons.
Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) out for more details about how to implement that kind of behavior, using tabs not buttons.